# Prestashop - basket total price

Tags: php, smarty, prestashop

it's me again with another Prestashop question.

In my template, I'd like to display total price in basket (cart) without using the module there, jsut simply display total price there and link to the basket ... is there a function, that will get this information from within the system?

`gettotalprice`

Or something like that?

Comment: Already found answer - but thansk for your time guys.

Comment: you could post your answer for the greater good!

Answer (score 4):

if you use the prestashop version 1.5 you should use this:

```
  Context::getContext()->cart->getOrderTotal(true);
```

best regards

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there is and it's a SMARTY function which you can use in your templates: `{$cart->getOrderTotal(true)}`, though **it only works up to Prestashop `v1.5`**, as noted in the comment below.

The code above will display total cart price with tax. If you don't want tax to be included in your total, change the parameter from `true` to `false`.

For Prestashop `v1.5+` you should use: `Context::getContext()->cart->getOrderTotal(true);`